# Kotlin when using kotlin("js") plugin how to use Thread class?

Tags: javascript, kotlin

In build.gradle.kts I moved using kotlin("jvm") to kotlin("js"), then I got the error message *Unresolved reference: Thread*

Is there a way to use the *Thread* class when compiling Kotlin to Js ? (Or how to then get the current class or current function name ?)

Comment: `Thread` is JVM only https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html

Comment: @al3c Then how to get the current class or current function name ?

Comment: I have no idea, I suspect it might not even be doable in vanilla JS (but I'm far far from being an expert). And Kotlin does not seem to have a platform portable way of doing it.